# Drop pin at current user location iphone mkmapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview, coordinates

Ok, here's my attempt at using CLLoactionManager

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    mapView=[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    //mapView.showsUserLocation=TRUE;
    mapView.delegate=self;
    [self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];


    CLLocationManager *locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    mStoreLocationButton.hidden=FALSE;
    location=newLocation.coordinate;
    //One location is obtained.. just zoom to that location

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center=location;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=0.01;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.01;
    region.span=span;

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];    
}
```

My problem is that `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` doesn't seem to fire the next method.  What am I missing?  I've tried setting breakpoints in the second method, but they never catch.  Obviously it's not being used.

Comment: If you don't want a pin, then you can just use [yourMapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into using a CLLocationManager to get the current location to feed your MKMapView with the correct coordinates.

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
MKMapView *map = [[MKMapView alloc] init];

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate = locationManager.location.coordinate;
MKCoordinateRegion extentsRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(_coordinate, 800, 800); 

[map setRegion:extentsRegion animated:YES];
```

Comment: Do I need to create a new class to implement this?  Or will this go in my above code?

Comment: This code is just the .m implementation.  Obviously you would need the header files as well.  I'll work up a more thorough example and post it within the next day or so.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917383/how-do-i-drop-a-pin-with-mapkit) looks like a good place to start. In order to drop a pin, you need to know the coordinates. Using `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation` will help you get the user's location so that you can create an `MKAnnotation` and `MKPinAnnotationViews`. Its pretty straight forward once you get started.

Comment: I tried to follow along with the guide, but `initWithCoordinate:coordinate andTitle:_title andSubtitle:_title` is giving me an error that there is no @interface that declares this selector.

Comment: Ahh, yes.. I forgot the annotation code.. thank you for pointing this out.  I'll include this in my revised example to be posted soon.