# Drop pin and get adress from where the user tap on map

Tags: swift, mkmapview, core-location

I'm trying to get the address and showing an annotation where the user presses on my map.

I'm new to swift and don't know where to begin any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to getAdress where the user taps that is a tricky part,

[By following this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580269/get-tapped-coordinates-with-iphone-mapkit)

OR

You can do with dragging by pin:

Step 1: Drop pin on current location. [By following this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894722/swift-mkmapview-drop-a-pin-annotation-to-current-location)

Step 2: By dragging pin you can get the current pin position address. [By following this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776853/ios-swift-mapkit-making-an-annotation-draggable-by-the-user)

Comment: Hi at the moment I have it to zoom into the current location of the user and showing a blue dot where the user is at(something like step 1), I would like the pin to work like in apple maps where long press on a location to show a pin with the adress

Comment: The first link worked, thanks. Before I had made the gestureRecognizer inside the storyboard but I changed it to create programmatically with solved my issue :)

Comment: Happy to help :)